# NullPointerException in graphics when trying to fill on a JPanel

Tags: java, graphics, nullpointerexception, jpanel, graphics2d

Basically, the point of this is to have worms that expand when the add worm button is clicked. Im trying to make one worm expand and eventually use multithreading to allow multiple worms to expand across the screen. At the moment I am trouble just allowing for the one worm to expand. Here is what my code looks like for the following classes, Main, ThreadFrame & DrawThread:

Main:

```
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ThreadFrame myFrame = new ThreadFrame();
    myFrame.setSize(new Dimension(640, 480));
    myFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    myFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    myFrame.setTitle("Worms! - Jonathan Perron");
    myFrame.setVisible(true);
    myFrame.setResizable(false);
}
}
```

ThreadFrame Class:

```
public class ThreadFrame extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

JButton btnNewWorm, btnKillWorm;
JPanel myPanel2 = new JPanel();
ArrayList<DrawThread> worms = new ArrayList<DrawThread>();

public JPanel getMyPanel2(){
    return this.myPanel2;
}

public ThreadFrame() {
    JPanel myPanel = new JPanel();
    btnNewWorm = new JButton("New Worm");
    btnKillWorm = new JButton("Kill Worm");
    myPanel.setBounds(0, 400, 640, 80);
    myPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    myPanel2.setSize(new Dimension(640, 400));
    myPanel2.setLayout(null);
    myPanel2.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    btnNewWorm.setBounds(100, 410, 200, 30);
    btnKillWorm.setBounds(340, 410, 200, 30);
    add(btnNewWorm);
    add(btnKillWorm);
    add(myPanel2);
    add(myPanel);
    btnNewWorm.addActionListener(this);
    btnKillWorm.addActionListener(this);
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent AE) {
    if(AE.getSource() == btnNewWorm){
        DrawThread dw = new DrawThread(myPanel2);
        worms.add(dw);
        System.out.println("New worm!");
    }
    if(AE.getSource() == btnKillWorm){
        System.out.println("Kill worm!");
    }
}
}
```

DrawThread Class:

```
public class DrawThread extends Thread implements Runnable{

Graphics2D g, graph;
private int sleepTime, wormDiameter, hue, saturation, brightness, randomWidth, randomHeight;

public DrawThread(int sleepTime, int wormDiamter, int hue, int saturation, int brightness, int randomWidth, int randomHeight) {
    this.sleepTime = sleepTime;
    this.brightness = brightness;
    this.hue = hue;
    this.saturation = saturation;
    this.randomWidth = randomWidth;
    this.randomHeight = randomHeight;
}

public int getSleepTime(){
    return sleepTime;
}

public void setSleepTime(int sleepTime){
    this.sleepTime = sleepTime;
}
public DrawThread(JPanel myPanel2){

    Random rand = new Random();

    //get panel dimensions
    int panelWidth = myPanel2.getWidth();
    int panelHeight = myPanel2.getHeight();

    //worm location
    randomWidth = rand.nextInt(panelWidth);
    randomHeight = rand.nextInt(panelHeight);

    //worm size
    wormDiameter = rand.nextInt(7)+3;

    //worm color 
    hue = rand.nextInt(255);
    saturation = rand.nextInt(255);
    brightness = rand.nextInt(255);
    Color color = new Color(hue, saturation, brightness);

    //sleep
    sleepTime = rand.nextInt(80) + 20;

    //Graphics
    System.out.println(myPanel2);
    g = (Graphics2D) myPanel2.getGraphics();
    g.setColor(color);
    Ellipse2D.Double ellipse2D = new Ellipse2D.Double(randomWidth, randomHeight, wormDiameter, wormDiameter);
    g.fill(ellipse2D);
    Thread thread1 = new Thread(new DrawThread(sleepTime, wormDiameter, hue, saturation, brightness, randomWidth, randomHeight));
    thread1.start();
}

public void run(){
    try { 
        while(true) { 
            sleep(sleepTime);
            Ellipse2D.Double ellipse2D = new Ellipse2D.Double(randomWidth + 10, randomHeight + 10, wormDiameter, wormDiameter);
            g.fill(ellipse2D); //This is where I receive my error
            System.out.println("ran");
        }
    } 
    catch (InterruptedException e) {
        System.out.println("ERROR!");
    }
}

public String toString() {
    String result = "SleepTime: " + sleepTime + "\nWorm Diameter: " + wormDiameter
            + "\nHue: " + hue + "\nSaturation: " + saturation + "\nBrightness: "
            + brightness + "\nWidth: " + randomWidth + "\nHeight: " + randomHeight;
    return result;
}
}
```

I receive my error in the DrawThread class when trying to fill the graphics, giving me a null pointer exception. Here's the exact error:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-4" java.lang.NullPointerException
at Main.DrawThread.run(DrawThread.java:78)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

How can I fix my code so I do not get this error?

Comment: g is null in your run method.

Comment: Yes! How do I make not null. Basically I need to make it so 'g' is not null and can display things on my JPanel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The instance variable g is null. This should be given a value in the appropriate constructor.

You have set it in the DrawThread(JPanel) constructor but not the other.

You may want to consider if this should be an instance variable or not. If so, set it appropriately in the other constructor.

[Edit] You could pass the JPanel into the other constructor and set g from it.

```
public DrawThread(int sleepTime, int wormDiamter, int hue, int saturation, int brightness, int randomWidth, int randomHeight, JPanel panel) {
    //...
    g = (Graphics2D) panel.getGraphics();
    //...
}
```

Comment: Why not? Can't you set a reference to the JPanel in the constructor then create a getter to access it? this.getMyPanel() or something?

Comment: James has the right answer.  Also with the way your run method works requires that your constructor (unless you have a setter) needs to have a Graphics object passed to it.

Comment: Thank you so much guys, this has cleared it up for me!

Comment: You should never use getGraphics, apart from the fact that it can return null, it's nothing more then a snapshot of the last paint cycle, anything painted to it will be removed tater the next paint cycle. Take a look at [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) for more details

Answer (score 1):

The reference to `Graphics2D` in your `DrawThread` is `null`.  While this is the initial problem, it is a symptom of a large problem.

Custom painting in Swing should be done from within the context of Swing component's paint methods, preferably, the `paintComponent` method.  See [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) for more details.

There are a number of reasons for this...

### Firstly

Swing is not thread safe.  This means, even if you got a reference to the components `Graphics` context, you could end up with dirty paints as you try and paint at the Swing painting process tries to update simultaneously.

As a side note `JComponent#getGraphics` can return `null` and as nothing more then a snapshot of the last paint cycle, meaning that anything painted to it will be erased on the next paint cycle.

This also means, that any interaction or modifications to the UI should be done from within the context of the Event Dispatching Thread and never from any other `Thread` context.

Take a look at [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for more details.

Generally speaking, for most basic animations, you should consider using a [`javax.swing.Timer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) instead of `Thread`.  This will ensure that all "ticks" of the timer are called from within the context of the Event Dispatching Thread...

### Secondly

Swing uses a passive rending algorithm.  This means that paint updates occur at irregular intervals and could occur for many reasons, most of which are outside of your control.

To be able to deal with this, you need to be painting within the context of Swing's painting process, typically by overriding `paintComponent`.

Normally painting is like painting onto a canvas, what ever you painted on it before will painted over, one of the jobs of `paintComponent` is to erase the view and repaint it from scratch.